# How to convert Iron Python dictionary to Python dictionary

Tags: python, ironpython

I need to convert a received IronPython dictionary variable to a regular Python dictionary. From what I understand the variable is so-called:

```
'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.String]'
```

If I use:

```
for each in IronDictionary:
    print type(each)
    print each
```

I am getting:

```
type: '<class 'System.Collections.Generic.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]'>'
'[MultiProcess, False]' # this line is a result of `print each` command
```

So in an essence `each` is just like a regular Python list...
It would be great if I could convert this entire Iron dictionary to a regular Python one. If it is not possible, I wouldn't mind to iterate using `for each in IronDict:` and converting every Iron `each` into a regular Python list or a Python string maybe?... How to accomplish this correctly?

Comment: What's the problem you are trying to solve with this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I can only suspect what you are asking for. 
Assuming your dictionary uses string as key and value, if you would like to create python dictionary from clr one, try:

```
pythondict = dict(clrdict)
```

And reverse direction:

```
from System.Collections.Generic import Dictionary
clrdict = Dictionary[str,str](pythondict)
```

You may also just try to use it as-is without converting.
Can you show why do you need a conversion?

EDIT:
This is working example:

```
from System.Collections.Generic import Dictionary
clrdict = Dictionary[str,str]()
clrdict.Add('k1','v1')
clrdict.Add('k2','v2')
pythondict=dict(clrdict)

print clrdict
print type(clrdict)
print pythondict
print type(pythondict)
```

Which produces:

```
Dictionary[str, str]({'k1' : 'v1', 'k2' : 'v2'})
<type 'Dictionary[str, str]'>
{'k2': 'v2', 'k1': 'v1'}
<type 'dict'>
```

Comment: While attempting to convert `clrdict`(which is IronPython  `'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.String]'`
 to Python dictionary using `pythondict = dict(clrdict)` I am getting `TypeError : cannot convert dictionary update sequence element #0 to a sequence (Python.Runtime.PythonException)`

Comment: which version of ironpython do you use? "cannot convert dictionary update sequence element #0 to a sequence" is a python message, but I can not find it in current 2.7.5b2.